# mach-o linker errors with metaio

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, linker-errors, mach-o

I am working with Metaio SDK and cloud plugin and I can not get past a huge collection of mach-o linker errors in xcode 5. Here are a few, but I have 118 of them:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      tesseract::WordListLangModel::AddString32(int const*) in metaioSDK(word_list_lang_model.o)
      std::basic_string<int, std::char_traits<int>, std::allocator<int> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<int, std::char_traits<int>, std::allocator<int> > const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) in metaioSDK(word_list_lang_model.o)
      tesseract::ConvNetCharKSBmHGiVwS::Fold() in metaioSDK(conv_net_classifier.o)
      tesseract::HybridNeuralNetCharKSBmHGiVwS::Fold() in metaioSDK(hybrid_neural_net_classifier.o)
  "std::string::operator[](unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      tesseract::CubeUtils::SplitStringUsing(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >*) in metaioSDK(cube_utils.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(std::string const&, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      tesseract::CubeUtils::SplitStringUsing(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >*) in metaioSDK(cube_utils.o)
  "std::string::length() const", referenced from:
      tesseract::WordUnigrams::Create(std::string const&, std::string const&) in metaioSDK(word_unigrams.o)
      tesseract::TesseractCubeCombiner::ComputeCombinerFeatures(std::string const&, int, tesseract::CubeObject*, tesseract::WordAltList*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, bool*) in metaioSDK(tesseract_cube_combiner.o)
      tesseract::ConvNetCharKSBmHGiVwS::LoadFoldingSets(std::string const&, std::string const&, tesseract::LangModel*) in metaioSDK(conv_net_classifier.o)
      tesseract::HybridNeuralNetCharKSBmHGiVwS::LoadFoldingSets(std::string const&, std::string const&, tesseract::LangModel*) in metaioSDK(hybrid_neural_net_classifier.o)
```

After setting deployment target to 6.0, I have cut this down to 6 errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventEditViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(XDtLkdmsHtXjGTCxiIGVbMqenrFYqNevtLOSg)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEvent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(XDtLkdmsHtXjGTCxiIGVbMqenrFYqNevtLOSg)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ASMoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(ASMoviePlayerViewController.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(MoviePlayerViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(XDtLkdmsHtXjGTCxiIGVbMqenrFYqNevtLOSg)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ASMoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(ASMoviePlayerViewController.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(MoviePlayerViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What happens if you target an earlier iOS version?

Comment: @Robert That cut them down to only 6! I posted the remaining 6 in an edit above. Any other great suggestions?

Comment: whats the version of metaio SDK you are using.

Comment: @Shabirjan I believe 4.5

Comment: Can you try removing armv7s from the build architectures (since you've already set it to iOS 6 only, you're not losing out on any actual devices).

Comment: @JaiGovindani By lowering my deployment target to 6, I can not run this on 7? I am currently trying to build to ios7 iphone 5s.

Comment: Understood, just wanted to take the testing a step further and see if removing armv7s will remove the rest of the errors - helps isolate it to an iOS 7/armv7s issue (in terms of frameworks, etc).

Comment: @JaiGovindani If I remove armv7s from "valid architectures" and from "architectures" it does not appear to make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you shown for iOS 6 means, that some of the frameworks are missing, Please add all these frameworks shown in the image to make it work with iOS 6.

[image]

and this [link](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/changelog/upgrade-to-45/) can help you as well.

New Update:

After checking your code, i found some problems in the your project, You were missing the `StoreKit and StoreKitUI and MeidaPlayer` Frameworks.

And some of your build setting configuration was not correct. Please use the exact configurations show in this images. `Other Linker flag` must be like that:

[image]

and `C Language dialect` must be like that:
[image]

and this configuration be exactly like this image:
[image]

i have tested the your app by using all these configuration and now the app is working fine with iOS7 and iOS 6.

Comment: I am certain I have all of the frameworks in that list. I made the other changes, and now I am back to 118 errors

Comment: can you send me the project ? so i can check it for you, i email is : iam.shabir yahoo.com

Comment: sent to your email, if you can fix it, can you let me know what you did so I can post it up here for future people. And so I can remember to do it myself on future apps?

Comment: See my updated answer , in the mean time i am checking ur project.

Comment: With your most recent update, I am back to the 6 original errors posted at the bottom of my Q.

Comment: @livinzlife please see my updated answer and check your app, by using this configuration the app is working fine with me.

Comment: I am now receiving this error "Malformed or corrupted AST file: 'mismatched umbrella headers in submodule'"  When I click the error it refers to #import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

Comment: did you checked the project in your email.

Comment: please check the framework search path and library search path, may be there is wrong path in there. i just executed the project successfully in my xcode.

Comment: got it... had to add "eventkit" "eventkitui" for it to run. The list of needed metaio frameworks (from their documentation) is far short of the actual requirements.

Comment: Hi I've done same as u mentioned.....facing error like this   "metaio::CreateUnifeyeMobileIPhone(std::string const&)", referenced from:


      -[UnifeyeMobileViewController viewDidLoad] in UnifeyeMobileViewController.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Pls pls pls help me

Answer (score 3):

EKEventEditViewController indicates that you are not linking against EventKitUI.framework.

SLComposeViewController indicates that you are not linking against Social.framework

Refer [Here](http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/14686/integrating-into-existing-app-linker-errors-ios-61)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all my errors by updating the sdk, I faced tons of problems (here: http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/38835/ios81-unity-455-metaio-60-sdk-mach-o-linker-errors-in-xcode-61)

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it with these configurations:

**Frameworks:**
[image: Imported Frameworks]

**Add linker Flag:**
[image: File config]

**Change ViewController extension to .mm:**
[image: mm extension]

**Inside Build Settings set Language C++ as follows:**
[image: Language C++ Settings]

**And set the C Language Dialect:**
[image: C Language Dialect]

**Also:**

Check all the frameworks are linked correctly

Check that all the files you need are registered inside "Build Phases > Compile Sources"

**Tested on iOS 8**